# How to use simple_smartsheet library?

Tags: python, sdk, smartsheet-api

I wanna use simple_smartsheet to update rows in Smartsheet by Python, but I even cannot open the Smartsheet with this library. I still try to open Smartsheet

```
import os
from datetime import date
from pprint import pprint

from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType

TOKEN = os.getenv('SMARTSHEET_API_TOKEN') # MY TOKEN HERE
SHEET_NAME = "BIM Request Measures Testing"
smartsheet = Smartsheet(TOKEN)

sheets = smartsheet.sheets.list()
print(sheets)
```

This is what the console showed

```
  File "C:\Users\kvuong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\functools.py", line 864, in register
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid first argument to `register()`. typing.Dict[typing.Tuple[str, ...], simple_smartsheet.types.IndexType] is not a class or union type.
```

I refer to that book [Reference](https://pypi.org/project/simple-smartsheet/)

I hope you can help me connect to Smartsheet by Python, Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `simple-smartsheet` is not actively maintained anymore. The last update is from February 2020. It seems that the library does not work with newer versions of Python. I tried using it with Python 3.11, 3.10 and 3.9 and got the same error.

The latest version of Python in which I managed to import Smartsheet from the library without any errors was **Python 3.8.10**. So, to resolve this issue switch to an older version of Python.

**Edit 2 Jan 2023:**

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/dmfigol/simple-smartsheet/pull/36) to fix this issue.

Comment: Plus, there already is a [pull request](https://github.com/dmfigol/simple-smartsheet/pull/36) to fix this issue, but I don't know if and when it will be merged.